# How can I load part of the image matrix for OpenCV's Mat structure into my own 3x3 array?

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I want to implement my own filters on the input image from a camera feed, in 3x3 blocks. How can I break up the Mat structure into my own 3x3 array?

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you mean you want to use convolution to filter the image with a 3x3 kernel?

Comment: I want to extract portions of the Mat image in 3x3 blocks which I can then process and load back into another Mat structure.

Answer (score 0):

There is two ways to extract part of image

using range:

> Mat ROI = Myimage(Range(0, 3), Range(0,3));

or using rect:

> Mat ROI = Myimage(Rect(0,0, 3 , 3));